# Как из разных форм обратиться к одному массиву?

Tags: c#, winforms

В проекте Windows Forms есть несколько форм. Нужно, что бы из каждой формы можно было обратиться к массиву. Например, из одной заполнить его, в другой вывести и т.д.. Где мне инициализировать этот массив, что бы можно было обращаться к нему из всех форм? П.с. массив типа int.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, для вашей задачи вполне пойдет такое решение:

```
public static class Holder
{
    static List<int> _array = new List<int>();

    public static List<int> GetArray
    {
        get { return _array; }
        set { array_ = value; }
    }    
}
```

Comment: А без классов это можно реализовать? )

Comment: @ProgerStudent, а зачем? ну сделайте в одном из code-behind public массив, и стучитесь к нему. только это как-то уж совсем...

Comment: совсем нубский вопрос: а что за code-behind?

Comment: файл Form1.cs и т.д.

Comment: ну вот я в нем прямо так пытаюсь объявить массив 
public int[] array;
если пытаюсь сделать это в namespace, выдает ошибку "требуется класс, делегат ..."
а если буду делать его в  
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
}
то, как я понял, он не будет виден другим формам

Comment: @ProgerStudent было бы неплохо, если бы вы соизволили пояснить, для чего вам это нужно. Тогда можно было бы подобрать оптимальное решение. Вариант от @Макс Жуков гораздо лучше всех этих невнятных манипуляций с Form1 по ряду причин. А просто добавить массив, не включая его ни в какие классы нельзя - язык полностью объектно-ориентированный.

Comment: Вопрос уже неактуален, реализовал совсем по другому: данные массива сохраняю в отдельный файл, и когда нужно с ними работать, считываю. Задача у меня достаточно простая и классы в ней совсем не хочется использовать. Но спасибо за информацию, что просто добавить массив нельзя - на будущее учту.

Comment: @ProgerStudent, вы меня, конечно, извините за нескромный вопрос...но если вам не хочется использовать "классы", то как вы пишете то? тем более на c#

Comment: >реализовал совсем по другому: данные массива сохраняю в отдельный файл, и когда нужно с ними работать, считываю

Ну вы даёте однако же. Зачем городить такие костыли? То, что вы придумали - это крайне неудачное и неоптимальное решение.

Comment: @ProgerStudent, если не хотите использовать класс (хотя это странно, сложность проекта при этом не увеличится, а удобочитаемость - однозначно), то сделайте ваш массив полем класса Form1. Делать это надо не в конструкторе. Пример:
public class Form1
{
    public static List<int> myArray = new List<int>();

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }  
}

И доступ к нему будет статичный, то есть Form1.myArray в пределах namespace